# Extract and concatinate json nodes in ansible

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I have Ansible task, where output get registered.
It is response of elastisearch request called by `curl/uri` module.

An example:

`{
  "changed": false,
  "msg": "All items completed",
  "results": [
    {
      "_ansible_item_result": true,
      "_ansible_no_log": false,
      "changed": false,
      "content_length": "747",
      "content_type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "invocation": {...},
      "item": "content",
      "json": {
        "snapshots": [
          {
            "duration_in_millis": 2863,
            "end_time": "2016-09-25T16:00:05.357Z",
            "end_time_in_millis": 1474819205357,
            "failures": [],
            "indices": [
              "content_h_20160817_1155",
              "content_s_20160817_1159",
              "content_p_20160817_1158",
              "content_t_20160909_0451",
              "content_v_20160909_0454",
              "content_h_20160909_0431",
              "content_v_20160817_1201",
              "content_m_20160817_1157",
              "content_m_20160909_0438",
              "content_p_20160909_0443",
              "content_t_20160817_1200",
              "content_i_20160817_1156",
              "content_i_20160909_0434",
              "content_s_20160909_0447"
            ],
            "shards": {
              "failed": 0,
              "successful": 28,
              "total": 28
            },
            "snapshot": "snapshot_content_20160925_1600",
            "start_time": "2016-09-25T16:00:02.494Z",
            "start_time_in_millis": 1474819202494,
            "state": "SUCCESS",
            "version": "2.3.3",
            "version_id": 2030399
          }
        ]
      },
      "msg": "OK (747 bytes)",
      "redirected": false,
      "status": 200,
      "url": "url"
    },
    {
      "_ansible_item_result": true,
      "_ansible_no_log": false,
      "changed": false,
      "content_length": "526",
      "content_type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "invocation": {...},
      "item": "log",
      "json": {
        "snapshots": [
          {
            "duration_in_millis": 5002,
            "end_time": "2016-09-25T16:01:24.174Z",
            "end_time_in_millis": 1474819284174,
            "failures": [],
            "indices": [
              "log_i_20160804_0749",
              "log_p_20160804_0811",
              "log_v_20160804_0847",
              "log_m_20160804_0758",
              "log_h_20160804_0746",
              "log_t_20160804_0829",
              "log_s_20160804_0825"
            ],
            "shards": {
              "failed": 0,
              "successful": 14,
              "total": 14
            },
            "snapshot": "snapshot_log_20160925_1600",
            "start_time": "2016-09-25T16:01:19.172Z",
            "start_time_in_millis": 1474819279172,
            "state": "SUCCESS",
            "version": "2.3.3",
            "version_id": 2030399
          }
        ]
      },
      "msg": "OK (526 bytes)",
      "redirected": false,
      "status": 200,
      "url": "url"
    }
  ]
}`

Next, I need to get only indices[] from each element in result.
How can I extract `indices[]` array from all `result[]` nodes into one variable, in order to be able to use `with_items` later?
Thanks.

PS. I omitted `invocation` elements, they are too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read about [map](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map) and [sum](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#sum).
Answer to your question:

```
curl_res.results | map(attribute='json.snapshots') | sum(start=[]) | map(attribute='indices') | sum(start=[])
```

You need to flatten lists with `sum` twice, because `snapshots` is a list too.

Comment: That what exactly I did @Konstantin, but did not get an idea to use sum. Thanks, let me test it tomorrow and respond you back.

Comment: Without `sum` you end up with list of lists and can't use `map` to extract attributes. `sum(start=[])` concatenates inner lists into one flat list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did know how to concatenate in Ansible, works as expected.